# How to fix Class 'app\hotelroom' not found error in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im new to laravel , i have created migration and the table (hotelroom) earlier but forgot to create the model for the same ,bu now after creating the model and trying to retrieve the data , im getting above error

This is where it highlights the error

```````````````````````````````````
namespace App\Http\Controllers; 

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\hotelroom;
class manage_roomscontroller extends Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->middleware('auth');
   }
   public function index()
   {
       $arr['hotelrooms']=hotelroom::all();
       return view('admin.rooms.index')->with($arr);
   }
}

Arguments
"Class 'app\hotelroom' not found" 
``````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````

model ( located under app directory)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class hotelroom extends Model
{

}
```

can someone tell me where the issue is? is it because i have created the model later ?( not at the same time while I created the migration). or its some other issue?

Comment: It should be `use App\hotelroom;` not `app`

Comment: Wrong namespace in `use` . it should be `App` and `app`.  use `use App\hotelroom;`

Answer (score 1):

This error is because of `app` which will not work, you need to put proper namespace name as like below

```
use App\hotelroom;
```

The app directory is namespaced under `App` by default. You can open `composer.json` file and see that the app directory is set up for psr-4 autoloading:

```
"psr-4": {
     "App\\": "app/"
 },
```

Comment: Ah !got it , Thanks a lot Ayaz

Comment: how do i do that?